# NuGet Packager not allowing a prerelease dependency in VSTS

Tags: nuget-package

When NuGet creates my package I get an error for including a prerelease package and it gives me the following result:

```
C:\LR\Mms\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\2.109.1\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe pack "C:\a\1\s\Harvest.Auth\Harvest.Auth.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\a\1\s" -Properties Configuration=release -version 1.0.1
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Attempting to build package from 'Harvest.Auth.csproj'.
Packing files from 'C:\a\1\s\Harvest.Auth\bin\Release'.
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
A stable release of a package should not have on a prerelease dependency. Either modify the version spec of dependency "Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (≥ 4.0.209160138-alpha)" or update the version field.
System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
```

I know that I need to mark my NuGet package as prerelease, however you can see in the first line it does not pickup my tag and version correctly which is 1.0.1-alpha, it only picks up 1.0.1.

I've also tried adding `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.1-alpha")]` per the NuGet documentation located [here](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/prerelease-packages), however this didn't work either.

I was hoping there would be a command line to force it to create anyway, since we use it internally, and don't really care if it's pre-release or not.  Here's the [pack](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference#pack) commands.

I should also note that we are using the NuGet packager that is part of VSTS.

Comment: Looks like by using a variable I can get it to accept the **1.0.1-alpha** version and properly create the nupkg, however it still doesn't help me in the automated CI part of what I'm trying to accomplish since I have to manually tell it what version it is rather than it grabbing it from either the assemblyinfo.cs file, the build number, or the git tag.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Your edit makes the error harder to read.

Comment: @Scratte We will have to agree to disagree, I read it easier w/o scrolling.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Then it's a difference in preference. Like code style. Editing a post that already has a preference isn't constructive, in my opinion. I like to see the individual lines, to scan until the important one comes. In a quote, it's not possible to do that. (I think also it's a quote because it's meant to be used for those, not for code or results)

Comment: @Scratte Well, the original formatting didn't garner an answer; so if that is constructive so be it.